# Is the set of all integers with metric $d(m,n)=|m-n|$ a complete space?

Tags: limits, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Consider the set of integers with a metric defined by $d(m,n)=|m-n|$.Is this set complete with respect to this metric?

If it is a metric, then I am stuck here. How can a Cauchy sequence have a limit in this set?

Comment: There are not many Cauchy sequences!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356985/is-the-set-of-integers-cauchy-complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What does $|m-n|<1$ imply for integers $m,n$?

**Solution:** (move mouse over to reveal)

> $|m-n|<1$ implies $m=n$ for all integers $m,n$. Therefore any Cauchy sequence in your space is eventually constant (why?), in particular convergent.

Comment: Thanks I have understood,since they are intergers